# Xamarin firebase different google-services.json for different build configurations

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android

In a xamarin.android project, we have 2 build configuration (Basic and Pro) also different Package Name.

On firebase we have registered two apps basic and pro in same project. So now we have two google-services.json file.

Now Problem is that - How can we handle different google-services.json file on different Build Configuration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Solved:** *Xamarin firebase different google-services.json for different compilation settings.*

After trying [@SushiHangover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4984832/sushihangover) solution, the following exception occurred when doing build, something like this:

> Failed to Read or Deserialize GoogleServicesJson file:
> google-services.json System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find
> file [your root directory]\google-services.json'.

at

> [your packages directory]\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.60.1142.1\build\MonoAndroid80\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets(66,5):
> error : Failed to Read or Deserialize GoogleServicesJson file:
> google-services.json.

### Solution: Using Pre-Build event command line

**1.** *Create the folder that contains the different google-services.json files at your [ProjectDir].*

Example:

> [ProjectDir]/GoogleServices >
>
> ```
> google-services-development.json
> google-services-production.json
> google-services-any.json
> ```

where *[ProjectDir]* is your project directory path.

**2.** *Create a fake* **google-services.json** *at your [ProjectDir] level.*

**3.** *Include that at your project.*

[image]

**4.** *Go to properties > Build Action> GoogleServicesJson*.

[image]

**5.** *Create your build configuration.* This is what you will use to change the configuration before compiling and executing the project and choosing which GoogleServiceJson will take action with your configuration.

*Go to Build> Configuration manager...> Active solution configuration > New...*

[image]

Set the name of your configuration and click Ok.

**6.** *Select the configuration you just created (Go to Build> Configuration manager...> Active solution configuration and select it, then close) and configure the command to copy the file from your folder **GoogleServices** to the **[ProjectDir]** in the pre-compiled event.*

*Go to Project> [Your project name] properties... > Build > Pre-Build event command line> Edit pre-build*

[image]

**7.** *Add your command to copy the file specified to your configuration.*

Example with production configuration:

[image]

Repeat steps from 5 to 7 for each google-service.json you have.

### Visual Studio for Windows Commands:

*Example command for development configuration:*

`COPY /Y "$(ProjectDir)GoogleServices\google-services-development.json" "$(ProjectDir)google-services.json"`

*Example command for production configuration:*

`COPY /Y "$(ProjectDir)GoogleServices\google-services-production.json" "$(ProjectDir)google-services.json"`

*Example command for any configuration:*

`COPY /Y "$(ProjectDir)GoogleServices\google-services-any.json" "$(ProjectDir)google-services.json"`

### Visual Studio for MAC Commands:

*Example command for development configuration:*

`cp "$(ProjectDir)GoogleServices\google-services-development.json" "$(ProjectDir)google-services.json"`

*Example command for production configuration:*

`cp "$(ProjectDir)GoogleServices\google-services-production.json" "$(ProjectDir)google-services.json"`

*Example command for any configuration:*

`cp "$(ProjectDir)GoogleServices\google-services-any.json" "$(ProjectDir)google-services.json"`

Now you can switch between Build configurations dinamically to execute the json you want. The Logic is create a Fake file to replace with the selected configuration using **Copy and Replace commands** as Pre-Build commands.

Comment: Andrespengineer couldn't you just leave the development one in the [ProjectDir] level and copy the Production one on the Prod build?

Comment: @j.t.h.I don't know now, but not then.  What happens is that the files are replaced.  If you have a file A (dev) and another B (prod) and replace A with B (prod build), when you switch to dev build, how will you replace B(prod) with A(dev), if A(dev) was literally removed with prod build? You need A => replace C and B => replace C, A and B should never be changed by a build operation.

Comment: @ Andrespengineer ah I understand now. It replaces the file in the directory and not just for the build. Did you find this solution to work better than the one mention by @SushiHangover? I tried his solution and I read about switching the FILE and INCLUDE but it shows both google-services-josn file in the project directory.

Answer (score 4):

You can conditionally include/exclude items in the `.csproj` based upon the Build Configuration

Note: You need to manually edit the `.csproj`, so make a backup

So assuming you have two debug configurations called `DebugPro`|`DebugBasic`, you could include a different `google-services.json` (say from a different directory) like so:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='DebugPro'">
    <GoogleServicesJson Include="google-services.json">
        <Link>Basic\google-services.json</Link>
    </GoogleServicesJson>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='DebugBasic'">
    <GoogleServicesJson Include="google-services.json">
        <Link>Pro\google-services.json</Link>
    </GoogleServicesJson>
</ItemGroup>
```

> MSBuild supports a specific set of conditions that can be applied wherever a Condition attribute is allowed. The following table explains those conditions.

(see link for condition expressions)

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2017

Comment: So if I put different json files in different directory it still looks for googleservices json file in root directory.If I remove json file from root then build fails

Comment: Are you using the `Link` property?

Comment: Yes..I am using exact code like you have provided..but after that build is failing saying could not find googleservices.json file in root folder

Comment: @SushiHangover-Are you able to implement this with your approach..Could you please guide me with detailed steps

Comment: @uncle_scrooge The text of the `Include` attribute and the `Link` element should be the other way round, so `Include` is the path to the real file and `Link` is just `google-services.json`.

Comment: As @Paul suggested the text between the Link and Include needs to be changed. If you get a Failed to Read or Deserialize GoogleServicesJson file: google-services.json it also might be to the occurence of special characters in the json file

Comment: Hey @SushiHangover I tried replicating the above-proposed solution but I am not sure if this is working or not can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57258402/different-google-services-json-googleservice-info-plist-for-ios-android-projec

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue, in MainActivity you can set dynamic values from ApplicationKey and APIKey
based on the package name
for dynamic package name I have create different Manifest file and added in .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'qaDebug|AnyCPU'">
    <AndroidManifest>Properties\AndroidManifest-qa.xml</AndroidManifest>
```

https://github.com/jamontes79/xamarin-forms-firebase-sample/blob/master/Droid/MainActivity.cs

Answer (score 0):

The [solution from Andrespengineer](http://Andrespengineer) is a good idea, but I couldn't find out how he's doing the switching of the build configuration, because you cannot change it at the build event page.

So I just entered it once and moved it from the end of the .csproj file to the end of my property group:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release-Prod|AnyCPU'">
    ...
    <PreBuildEvent>COPY /Y "$(ProjectDir)GoogleServices\prod\google-services.json" "$(ProjectDir)google-services.json"</PreBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: How to get this work in Mac? COPY command doesn't exist when build using Visual Studio on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio for Mac (ver.8.9.4) the syntax that worked for me is:

```
cp "${ProjectDir}/GoogleServices/google-services-development.json" "${ProjectDir}/google-services.json"
```